# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> m=np.mat('1,0;0,1')
>>> l=[m]
>>> m in l
True
>>> l=[np.mat('1,0;0,1')]
>>> m in l
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on here? I'm trying to make a list of numpy matrices and check if certain matrices are elements of this list, but I keep hitting this error.